# Transform XML to JSON in serverside javascript on MarkLogic

Tags: json, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have the following xml retrieved from a document:

```
<res>
  <basic:coordinates type="array" xmlns:basic="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
    <basic:item type="number">12.1479335</basic:item>
    <basic:item type="number">-68.2676857</basic:item>
  </basic:coordinates>
</res>
```

Now I want this to be transformed to JSON like:

```
{"coordinates": [0.0,0.0]}
```

I have a query like:

```
resjson.coordinates = 
  xdmp.toJSON(fn.string(
      res.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic",
        "coordinates")));
```

gives

```
"coordinates": "12.1479335-68.2676857"
```

Which is not an array...

Answer (score 1):

hmmm I was hoping for a more elegant solution, as the coordinates is already an array... but :

```
var pnts = res.xpath(".//basic:item/text()", {"basic":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic"});
res.coordinates = xdmp.toJSON(pnts);
```

does the trick

Comment: please accept your answer so that it's clear this one has a solution